# Actionscript countdown timer missing out numbers

Tags: actionscript-3, timer

I am still working on my game and have almost finished.
The problem I have at the moment is that the countdown timer I have written doesn't work as I wanted.
I have a 30 second countdown written in it's own class and it works fine there.
Once I paste it into my games code it counts from 30 to 7 then game over in just 2 - 3 seconds.
I am pretty sure it is something to do with the framerate overriding the timer but I cannot for the life of me figure out how to stop it.
I understand that it isn't the program, it is something I haven't taken into account but, after a whole weekend of trying to figure it out, I am stumped as to a solution.

This is the code ...

```
        public class MyGame extends MovieClip {


        public function MyGame() {           

            const BG_SPEED:int = 5;
            const BG_MIN:int =  -550;
            const BG_MAX:int = 0;
            const PBG_SPEED:int = 3;            

            var bg:BackGround = new BackGround; 
            var paraBg:ParaBg = new ParaBg;
            var toybox:TargetBox = new TargetBox;
            var toy:Toy = new Toy;
            var cheer:Cheer = new Cheer;
            var eightBit:EightBit = new EightBit;
            var countDown:Number = 30;
            var myTimer:Timer = new Timer(1000);
            var myText:TextField = new TextField;
            var myTextFormat:TextFormat = new TextFormat;
            var font:Font = new Font;

            var score:int = 0;

            var toy1:Toy1 = new Toy1;
            var toy2:Toy2 = new Toy2;
            var toy3:Toy3 = new Toy3;
            var toy4:Toy4 = new Toy4;
            var toy5:Toy5 = new Toy5;
            var toy6:Toy6 = new Toy6;
            var toy7:Toy7 = new Toy7;
            var toy8:Toy8 = new Toy8;
            var toy9:Toy9 = new Toy9;
            var toy10:Toy10 = new Toy10;
            var toy11:Toy11 = new Toy11;
            var toy12:Toy12 = new Toy12;
            var toy13:Toy13 = new Toy13;
            var toy14:Toy14 = new Toy14;
            var toy15:Toy15 = new Toy15;
            var toy16:Toy16 = new Toy16;
            var toy17:Toy17 = new Toy17;
            var toy18:Toy18 = new Toy18;
            var toy19:Toy19 = new Toy19;
            var toy20:Toy20 = new Toy20;

            var toyArray:Array = new Array(toy1, toy2, toy3, toy4, toy5, toy6, toy7, toy8, toy9, toy10, toy11, toy12, toy13, toy14, toy15, toy16, toy17, toy18, toy19, toy20);

            eightBit.play(0, 9999);

            addChildAt(paraBg, 0);
            addChildAt(bg, 1);  
            addChild(toy);
            toy.x = 306;
            toy.y = 133;
            addChild(toybox);
            toybox.x = 295;
            toybox.y = 90;

            bg.addEventListener(Event.ENTER_FRAME, bgScroll);           


            myText.text = countDown.toString();         
            myTimer.start();

            function addToys(xpos:int, ypos:int)
            {               
                addChild(toyArray[i]);
                toyArray[i].x = xpos;
                toyArray[i].y = ypos;                               
            }

            for (var i:int = 0; i < toyArray.length; i++)
            {
                addToys(1140 * Math.random() + 20, 170 * Math.random() + 230);                  
            }

            function bgScroll (e:Event)
            {
                if (stage.mouseX > 600 && bg.x > BG_MIN)
                {
                    bg.x -= BG_SPEED;   
                    paraBg.x -= PBG_SPEED;

                    for (var i:int=0; i< toyArray.length; i++)
                    {
                    (toyArray[i] as MovieClip).x -=BG_SPEED
                    }

                }
                else if (stage.mouseX < 50 && bg.x < BG_MAX)
                {
                    bg.x += BG_SPEED;
                    paraBg.x += PBG_SPEED;
                    for (var j:int=0; j< toyArray.length; j++)
                    {
                    (toyArray[j] as MovieClip).x +=BG_SPEED
                    }                           
                }

                for (var k:int = 0; k < toyArray.length; k++)
                {
                    toyArray[k].addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_DOWN, arrayGrab);
                }               

                stage.addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_UP, arrayDrop);

                function arrayGrab(e:MouseEvent)
                {
                    e.target.startDrag();
                }

                function arrayDrop(e:MouseEvent)
                {
                    e.target.stopDrag();

                }

                function collision (e:Event)
                {           
                    for (var l:int=0; l< toyArray.length; l++)
                        {                       
                            if (toyArray[l].hitTestObject(toy))
                            {
                                removeChild(toyArray[l]);
                                toyArray[l].x=100000;
                                toybox.gotoAndPlay(2);
                                cheer.play(1, 1);
                                score = score + 10;
                                trace(score);
                            }                               
                    }                       

                }
                e.target.addEventListener(Event.ENTER_FRAME, collision);
                myTimer.addEventListener(TimerEvent.TIMER, countdown);

            function displayText():void
            {   myText.filters = [new GlowFilter(0x00FF00, 1.0, 5, 5, 4)];
                addChild(myText);
                myText.width = 500, myText.height = 200, myText.x = 400, myText.y = 20;     
                myTextFormat.size = 30, myTextFormat.font = font.fontName;                  
                myText.setTextFormat(myTextFormat);
            }

            function displayText2():void
            {   myText.filters = [new GlowFilter(0x00FF00, 1.0, 5, 5, 4)];
                addChild(myText);
                myText.width = 500, myText.height = 200, myText.x = 200, myText.y = 20;     
                myTextFormat.size = 30, myTextFormat.font = font.fontName;                  
                myText.setTextFormat(myTextFormat);
            }



        function countdown(e:TimerEvent):void
            {           

                if (countDown > 0)
                {
                    countDown--;
                }
                myText.text = countDown.toString();

                if (countDown == 0)
                {
                    myText.text = "GAME OVER!";
                }

                displayText();

            }
            displayText();

        }



        }
    }

}
```

I have tried moving the timer listener with varying results, none of which are desired.

Any ideas what I am doing wrong?

Comment: You can start by verify your `bgScroll` function because I think that `myTimer.addEventListener(TimerEvent.TIMER, countdown)` should be outside this function.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your issue has to do with nested functions.

You have this method called `bgScroll`, and it's being run **EVERY FRAME**.   Inside this method, you attach an event listener to the `Timer`.  So every frame, you are adding a new listener to the timer event. Since the `countdown` method is nested within the `bgScroll` method, a new instance of that method gets created every frame and attached to the timer.

So your `countdown` method ends up being called 1 time on the first frame,  2 times on the second frame, 3 times on the third etc.   So it basically is counting down exponentially.

To fix this,  **DON'T NEST FUNCTIONS!!!** - especially inside of methods that run every frame. This has memory leak written all over it.

Break out all your methods that are inside `bgScroll` so they are in the class scope.  Also, break out `bgscroll` so it is also in the class scope.

As an example, your code should look more like this: (this is not what you're exact code should be, just an illustration of what I mean by breaking out your methods so everything isn't nested)

```
public class MyGame extends MovieClip
{

    const BG_SPEED:int = 5;
    const BG_MIN:int = -550;
    const BG_MAX:int = 0;
    const PBG_SPEED:int = 3;

    var bg:BackGround = new BackGround;
    var paraBg:ParaBg = new ParaBg;
    var toybox:TargetBox = new TargetBox;
    var toy:Toy = new Toy;
    var cheer:Cheer = new Cheer;
    var eightBit:EightBit = new EightBit;
    var countDown:Number = 30;
    var myTimer:Timer = new Timer(1000);
    var myText:TextField = new TextField;
    var myTextFormat:TextFormat = new TextFormat;
    var font:Font = new Font;

    var score:int = 0;

    var toy1:Toy1 = new Toy1;
    var toy2:Toy2 = new Toy2;
    var toy3:Toy3 = new Toy3;
    var toy4:Toy4 = new Toy4;
    var toy5:Toy5 = new Toy5;
    var toy6:Toy6 = new Toy6;
    var toy7:Toy7 = new Toy7;
    var toy8:Toy8 = new Toy8;
    var toy9:Toy9 = new Toy9;
    var toy10:Toy10 = new Toy10;
    var toy11:Toy11 = new Toy11;
    var toy12:Toy12 = new Toy12;
    var toy13:Toy13 = new Toy13;
    var toy14:Toy14 = new Toy14;
    var toy15:Toy15 = new Toy15;
    var toy16:Toy16 = new Toy16;
    var toy17:Toy17 = new Toy17;
    var toy18:Toy18 = new Toy18;
    var toy19:Toy19 = new Toy19;
    var toy20:Toy20 = new Toy20;

    var toyArray:Array = new Array(toy1, toy2, toy3, toy4, toy5, toy6, toy7, toy8, toy9, toy10, toy11, toy12, toy13, toy14, toy15, toy16, toy17, toy18, toy19, toy20);

    public function MyGame()
    {

        eightBit.play(0, 9999);

        addChildAt(paraBg, 0);
        addChildAt(bg, 1);
        addChild(toy);
        toy.x = 306;
        toy.y = 133;
        addChild(toybox);
        toybox.x = 295;
        toybox.y = 90;

        bg.addEventListener(Event.ENTER_FRAME, bgScroll);

        myText.text = countDown.toString();
        myTimer.start();

        for (var i:int = 0; i < toyArray.length; i++)
        {
            addToys(1140 * Math.random() + 20, 170 * Math.random() + 230);
        }

        stage.addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_UP, arrayDrop);

        e.target.addEventListener(Event.ENTER_FRAME, collision);
        myTimer.addEventListener(TimerEvent.TIMER, countdown);
    }

    function addToys(xpos:int, ypos:int)
    {
        addChild(toyArray[i]);
        toyArray[i].x = xpos;
        toyArray[i].y = ypos;
    }

    function bgScroll(e:Event)
    {
        if (stage.mouseX > 600 && bg.x > BG_MIN)
        {
            bg.x -= BG_SPEED;
            paraBg.x -= PBG_SPEED;

            for (var i:int = 0; i < toyArray.length; i++)
            {
                (toyArray[i] as MovieClip).x -= BG_SPEED
            }

        }
        else if (stage.mouseX < 50 && bg.x < BG_MAX)
        {
            bg.x += BG_SPEED;
            paraBg.x += PBG_SPEED;
            for (var j:int = 0; j < toyArray.length; j++)
            {
                (toyArray[j] as MovieClip).x += BG_SPEED
            }
        }

        for (var k:int = 0; k < toyArray.length; k++)
        {
            toyArray[k].addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_DOWN, arrayGrab);
        }

        displayText();

    }

    function arrayGrab(e:MouseEvent)
    {
        e.target.startDrag();
    }

    function arrayDrop(e:MouseEvent)
    {
        e.target.stopDrag();

    }

    function collision(e:Event)
    {
        for (var l:int = 0; l < toyArray.length; l++)
        {
            if (toyArray[l].hitTestObject(toy))
            {
                removeChild(toyArray[l]);
                toyArray[l].x = 100000;
                toybox.gotoAndPlay(2);
                cheer.play(1, 1);
                score = score + 10;
                trace(score);
            }
        }

    }

    function displayText():void
    {
        myText.filters = [new GlowFilter(0x00FF00, 1.0, 5, 5, 4)];
        addChild(myText);
        myText.width = 500, myText.height = 200, myText.x = 400, myText.y = 20;
        myTextFormat.size = 30, myTextFormat.font = font.fontName;
        myText.setTextFormat(myTextFormat);
    }

    function displayText2():void
    {
        myText.filters = [new GlowFilter(0x00FF00, 1.0, 5, 5, 4)];
        addChild(myText);
        myText.width = 500, myText.height = 200, myText.x = 200, myText.y = 20;
        myTextFormat.size = 30, myTextFormat.font = font.fontName;
        myText.setTextFormat(myTextFormat);
    }

    function countdown(e:TimerEvent):void
    {

        if (countDown > 0)
        {
            countDown--;
        }
        myText.text = countDown.toString();

        if (countDown == 0)
        {
            myText.text = "GAME OVER!";
        }

        displayText();

    }
}
```

Comment: Right, I see!
So I was right about the frame rate being part of the problem, but nesting them compounded the issue further?
I try to solve these things but, if I can't, I like to try to understand what I did wrong so I can (hopefully) avoid making the mistake again, so I hope you forgive all my questioning!
Am I right in thinking that, because they were nested, some functions couldn't access others and some just outright conflicted?

Comment: You just need to understand scope.  The frame is part of the problem in that every frame you add another listener to the timer, So frame 1 your count would be `29`, frame 2 `27` frame 3 `24` frame 4 `20` etc.  You only want one `TIMER` listener, so you can't attach it in a method that runs more than once.

Comment: anything contained in `public function MyGame(){` (your constructor) should just be things that need to happen when your game first runs.  Any variables and methods that need to persist beyond when the game is first loaded, should be defined NOT in the constructor (see where I moved all the vars?).

Comment: I understand what you mean. I worked on it over the last couple of days and, with your advice, made it work.
Thank you. Only thing I need to figure out now is why my 30 second Timer doesn't display text starting at 30 but at 29! Any ideas?

Comment: Because you decriment your `countDown` var before you assign the value to the text field.  (which is correct if you want it to end after showing `0` to the user), but that means your first time through it's going to display 29.  What you probably want to do, is make it 31 to start (or check against -1 instead of 0 as the end), and call `countdown(null);` at the same time you start the timer.